# Allocating Memory with Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I'm new to C++, trying to follow a tutorial series to learn the language, the challenge given for allocating memory is to allocate memory for 26 chars and then fill them with the alphabet, abcde... etc.

I thought I knew the solution but ran into this error: 
`Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00490000, 0049D9EC )` the part that is throwing me off is the program executes fully, a-z but still throws this error

Here is my code:

```
char c = 'a';
char *pChar = new char[26];

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++, pChar++, c++) {
    *pChar = c;
    cout << *pChar << flush;
}

delete[] pChar;
```

Sorry if the question is worded poorly, I am new to both c++ and stackoverflow.

Comment: Why don't you just declare a `char strAlphabet[27];' variable and in your `for` loop direcftly access the index with `strAlphabet[i] = c;`? Then set the last one (index 26, position 27 to `\0`). This way you don't worry about pointers and memory allocation/deallocation. Then just feed the `strAlphabet` once to cout after the loop? Or are you working on a excercise about using pointers?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle not an issue this time, `*pChar` is only printing a single character, but important note to be aware of. `cout << pChar;` (note the missing `*`) wanders into undefined behaviour. What will probably happen is the program will keep printing until it finds a null character or the program crashes, but it would be just as valid for the computer to grow legs and salsa dance around your room.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I picked up on that it did a single character. I guess I just wouldn't write the task the way it was presented.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The exercise is to use pointers and allocate memory, otherwise I would have gone about it a different way.

Comment: A lot of different ways to do this. For example, and outside the scope of this project, [take a look at `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). It automates the clean-up of dynamically allocated memory so that it can't (1) be forgotten or missed. (1) of course a suitably crafty and stupid programmer can still get around this, but they have to work at it. Don't do this: `std::unique_ptr<int> * BadIdea = new std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(10));`

Comment: @user4581301: That sounds like an error in the mood to reproduce.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the addition suggestion but this tutorial is focused on C++98, then I'll move on to C++11 and 14 to use unique_ptr, vector, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `delete[] pChar;` you are in fact attempting to delete what `pChar` is currently pointing at, which is not the same spot as where it was originally allocated.

In short, when you allocate something with `new` it puts some data about the allocation (size of the allocation for example so you do not need to say `delete[26] pChar;` like you had to when C++ was new) usually to the left of the newly allocated memory, and it is probably interpreting things you have written (the alphabet) as that information when trying to use it to free the memory, which is of course not going to work.

You should store a copy of the original pointer to the memory you have allocated instead and use that to delete, or perhaps a better option, use `i` and subscripts to index via pointer arithmetic instead like:

```
char c = 'a';
char *pChar = new char[26];

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++, c++) {
    pChar[i] = c;
    cout << pChar[i] << flush;
}

delete[] pChar;
```

Comment: Thank you, I created a *pStart pointer to store that original memory location and now it runs perfect, I'll accept this answer once it allows me!

Comment: @WillScott: What you really should be doing is using `std::string` or at least `std::vector` instead. Try to stay away from `new[]` and `delete[]` as much as you can, let the STL do the work for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau As previously stated the only reason I am using new and delete is to practice memory allocation following a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that when control leaves the loop, `pChar` points to a location one past the end of the array. You then call `delete[]` on that pointer, which is like putting a wrecking ball through the wrong house.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the other answers, you cannot call `delete[]` on a pointer you have changed since calling `new []`. It's undefined behavior.

`delete []` needs to get passed the exactly same pointer value as you had achieved when calling `new[]`.

---

And here's the most simple fix, without need to change `pChar`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{        
    char c = 'a';
    char *pChar = new char[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        pChar[i] = c; // access the character by index ...
        std::cout << pChar[i] << std::flush; // access the character by index ...
        // ++pChar; DON'T change the original pointer
        ++c;
    }

    delete[] pChar;
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79481895f4799300)

Comment: Sorry but why is this needed?  The accepted answer already include this.